# How to interpret c++ error messages displayed on the console?

Tags: c++, opencv, console, runtime-error

I am new to C++ and I have no good understanding of how to read and interpret the c++ error messages displayed on the console. Following is an error message when I was playing with some images in OpenCV. I know this should be an error related to the indexes of Mat files and dimensions of the Mat matrix data structures. But I want to learn how to read the error message bit by bit.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (un
signed)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1
]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) &
 ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file e:\opencv\build\i
nclude\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 538
```

Comment: This is not a C++ (compiler) error. It is a failed assertion. Assertions verify runtime conditions, and this message contains the conditions that must be met. The expression is regular C++ code.

Comment: @IInspectable Can u please interpret this message(line by line) ?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga, It's all one line and it doesn't have much meaning on its own unless, perhaps, you're familiar with this part of the code within OpenCV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is about **practical** programming problems. Failure to read code is not a practical programming problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it's a OpenCV error that tells you that some assumptions to perform an action don't hold. for example dims <= 2 means that some dimensions (most often number of matrix channels) must be <= 2.

Comment: I hoped anyone would help as stackoverflow is to help programmers, stucked while coding :D ... and I am happy and grateful to @Micka for being a honest supporter, while some others have forgot the stkof objective. I am new to c++ and for me this a practical programming problem..!!

Comment: @Barry I hoped a practiced expert in opencv and c++ would understand this common "error" easily.

Comment: stackoverflow is **not** about helping individual developers. It is a Q&A site, providing a database of **common** programming problems.

Comment: A database of common programming problems would be used by individual programmers, but not by machines. (or not used as historical archives). Cheers..! and thanks..!!!

Comment: Failure to read code - while common among the general population - is **not** a common programming problem among developers.

Comment: Your probable final conclusion seems as this issue is caught by general public idling on road or doctors, traders, architects, politicians, etc... Ha ha.. this might earn u more reputations...
@Micka Thanx for your support. Can u interpret what is meant by the i0 in "(unsigned)i0" ?

Comment: try to find out which openCV function gives the error. most asserts are quite clear but yours are really a little cryptic ;)

Comment: @Micka As seems the errors is given when running the function at(). In my code it is occurred when I try to run following code>>  dems_linesonly.at<Vec3b>(l[0], l[1])[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[First read up on assertions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert).

Usually it's a test for inputs or the call of a function passing in something wrong, unusual, and fatal. If the test passes, the program lives. If the test fails, it dies in a brutal and very noticeable fashion to make sure the error is fixed.

Standard fix is to:

1. Use a debugger to determine which function asserted.
2. Read up on the documentation for the function that asserted and make sure you are passing in the correct data and have made the correct calls to configure the system before calling the asserting function.

Onward to the break-down.

```
(dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1())
```

this is the boolean logic that failed. It is implementation specific. Specifically this is a set of 5 tests, all of which must be passed or the program terminates.

```
dims <= 2
```

Dims is less than or equal to 2

```
data
```

data is not zero. Probably a null pointer test.

```
(unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]
```

i0, whatever that is, is less than size.p[0], whatever that is.

```
(unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels())
```

Number off channels is less than something else's number of channels.

```
((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()
```

This looks to me like the bit depth of something must be correct. Without context I can't be sure.

The rest

```
in cv::Mat::at, file e:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 538
```

is just the line number and the file where the assertion occurred.

Comment: By the way I found the error by debugging my program. The error has occurred as I was trying to access an index of a Mat object which was not available. i.e: matObjectName.at<uchar>(row,col); The col number I was using was exceeding the maximum columns in the Mat object. (it is like an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in java). This is interesting now.!!! So I guess the the test which has been failed is test no. 3:  (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0] . Am I correct ?

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga too little context for me to know. It's not 2 or 5, and unlikely to be 1, but I can't eliminate  3 or 4. This is exactly why one should use descriptive variable names. I have no *expletive deleted* clue what `i0`, `i1`, or `p` represent.

Comment: The case is that I have not used i0, i1 or p as variable names anywhere in my code. I guess they have come from some opencv library class which I have imported and used and that is actually the place where the error is rooted.

Comment: I guessed that there is no relation to number of channels in the error. (errors related to number of channels are usually occurred when we wrongly use the number of available channels of a image. ) So I think we can eliminate the 4.